# RFQ Engine design in Sell Side

Tags: risk-management, order-execution, quote

I am new to the eTrading and RFQ world and am learning these applications / services used within sell-side orgs like Investment banks in some details.

As Far as I know , the RFQ engine involves the below functions :

1. Receive a Quote Request from client platform for a security , for certain amount.
2. Generate a Price for that request and send a Quote to the client platform.
3. Stream additional quotes if needed.
4. Receive a Order from client if they accept the quote.
5. Execute the Order and fill the trade, send the execution back to client.
6. Manage the Trade Booking internally for settlement.
7. Manage the Risk positions.

Are these steps a fair representation of an RFQ engine ? Would it be expected to do anymore of significant functions apart from these ?

I wanted to understand each of the steps with some details. Are there any references / Books / resources I can refer ?

Comment: I think only "Generate a Price" bit is on-topic here. However it's more complicated than it sounds. For example, sometimes the  objective is not to generate the best price, but rather a price that is not the best, but close enough to the best to not look ridiculous.